# Flutter how to migrate BLoC old version code to Bloc 8.0.1 version

Tags: flutter, migration, bloc, flutter-bloc

While studying of Bloc migration from old version to new 8. I couldn't fix to convert to new version. I have faced many undefined thing which I haven't figure it out.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:WeatherApp/events/WeatherEvent.dart';
import 'package:WeatherApp/models/Weather.dart';
import 'package:WeatherApp/services/WeatherService.dart';
import 'package:WeatherApp/states/WeatherState.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class WeatherBloc extends Bloc<WeatherEvent, WeatherState> {
  WeatherBloc() : super(null) {
    add(WeatherCurrentPositionRequested());
  }

  @override
  Stream<WeatherState> mapEventToState(WeatherEvent event) async* {
    if (event is WeatherRequested) {
      yield* _newWeatherRequested(event);
    }
    if (event is WeatherCurrentPositionRequested) {
      yield* _newWeatherCurrentPositionRequested();
    }
  }

  Stream<WeatherState> _newWeatherRequested(WeatherRequested event) async* {
    yield WeatherLoadInProgress();
    try {
      final Weather weather = await WeatherService.fetchCurrentWeather(
          query: event.city, lon: event.lon, lat: event.lat);
      final List<Weather> hourlyWeather =
          await WeatherService.fetchHourlyWeather(
              query: event.city, lon: event.lon, lat: event.lat);
      yield WeatherLoadSuccess(weather: weather, hourlyWeather: hourlyWeather);
    } catch (e) {
      yield WeatherLoadFailure();
    }
  }

  Stream<WeatherState> _newWeatherCurrentPositionRequested() async* {
    LocationPermission permission = await checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse ||
        permission == LocationPermission.always) {
      Position lastKnownPosition = await getLastKnownPosition();
      if(lastKnownPosition != null) {
        add(WeatherRequested(
            lat: lastKnownPosition.latitude.toString(),
            lon: lastKnownPosition.longitude.toString()));

      } else {
        Position position =
        await getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
        add(WeatherRequested(
            lat: position.latitude.toString(),
            lon: position.longitude.toString()));
      }
    } else {
      await requestPermission();
      add(WeatherCurrentPositionRequested());
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/evgenusov/FlutterWeatherApp/blob/master/lib/bloc/WeatherBloc.dart

Answer (score -1):

This should works.

You also need to change the flutter bloc dependencies to latest to get this work.

```
import 'package:WeatherApp/events/WeatherEvent.dart';
import 'package:WeatherApp/models/Weather.dart';
import 'package:WeatherApp/services/WeatherService.dart';
import 'package:WeatherApp/states/WeatherState.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class WeatherBloc extends Bloc<WeatherEvent, WeatherState> {
  WeatherBloc() : super(WeatherInitial()) {
    on<WeatherRequested>((event, emit) async {
      emit(WeatherLoadInProgress());
      try {
        final Weather weather = await WeatherService.fetchCurrentWeather(
            query: event.city, lon: event.lon, lat: event.lat);
        final List<Weather> hourlyWeather =
            await WeatherService.fetchHourlyWeather(
                query: event.city, lon: event.lon, lat: event.lat);
        emit(
            WeatherLoadSuccess(weather: weather, hourlyWeather: hourlyWeather));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(WeatherLoadFailure());
      }
    });

    on<WeatherCurrentPositionRequested>((event, emit) async {
      LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse ||
          permission == LocationPermission.always) {
        Position lastKnownPosition = await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition();
        if (lastKnownPosition != null) {
          add(WeatherRequested(
              lat: lastKnownPosition.latitude.toString(),
              lon: lastKnownPosition.longitude.toString()));
        } else {
          Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
          add(WeatherRequested(
              lat: position.latitude.toString(),
              lon: position.longitude.toString()));
        }
      } else {
        await Geolocator.requestPermission();
        add(WeatherCurrentPositionRequested());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The bloc provider needs the following signature to work.

```
BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => WeatherBloc()
    ..add(
      WeatherCurrentPositionRequested(),
    ),
  child: ... your code
),
```